# Smudge multiple layers at once (GIMP)

Tags: gimp

I have two images (in two different layers) placed next to each other. I want to make the transition between them appear smooth with the Sumdge tool. How can I smudge the edges of the two images so that the Smudge tool works with both at the same time?

Comment: You can merge two layers together (Ctrl+M)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a Layer mask for the top one, white where you want the top image, black where the bottom image should be visible, and smudge the mask. But... if you are using masks, a white to black gradient on the mask works just as well:

[image]